# Elastic search "ERROR", "message":"blocking [indices:monitor/stats] operation due to expired license

Tags: spring-boot

I have setup elastic search with spring boot app by using docker compose and elastic search working fine. but when i open the log i can see that log appearing with below error message.

```
log.level":"ERROR", "message":"blocking [indices:monitor/stats] operation due to expired license. Cluster health, cluster stats and indices stats \noperations are blocked on license expiration. All data operations (read and write) continue to work. \nIf you have a new license, please update it. Otherwise, please reach out to your support contact.",
```

I am using below environments for elastic search as follows

```
MEM_LIMIT=
node.name=
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME
cluster.name=
discovery.type=
bootstrap.memory_lock=
ELASTIC_PASSWORD=
"ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms524m -Xmx1g"
xpack.license.self_generated.type=
xpack.security.enabled=
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled='true'
xpack.security.http.ssl.key=
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode= 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=
xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=
MAX_RESULT_WINDOW=
```

I have removed the envs as xpack.license.self_generated.type= but seems the same error message.